# Improve SVG so pin is centered inside circle, without multiple viewboxes

Tags: svg

I have a pin that needs to be shown inside a circle in Svg.

My current code is the following:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="1.5" r="1.5" style="fill: green;"></circle>
    <svg x="47.5%" y="5%" viewBox="0 0 10000 10000" fill="#fff" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <g>
            <path d="M250,124.3c-35,0-63.4,28.8-63.4,64.1c0,35.3,28.5,64,63.4,64s63.4-28.8,63.4-64.1C313.4,153,285,124.3,250,124.3z
 M250,222c-18.3,0-33.2-15.1-33.2-33.7s14.9-33.7,33.2-33.7s33.2,15.1,33.2,33.7S268.3,222,250,222z">
            </path>
            <path d="M250,50.9c-74.9,0-135.8,61.6-135.8,137.4c0,31.3,22.5,84.4,66.9,157.7c32.9,54.4,66.2,100.3,66.6,100.7l2.4,3.3l2.4-3.3
 c0.3-0.5,33.7-46.3,66.6-100.7c44.4-73.3,66.9-126.4,66.9-157.7C385.8,112.5,324.9,50.9,250,50.9z M250,397.6
 c-16.5-24.3-45.5-68.4-69.9-114c-23.5-44-35.9-77-35.9-95.4c0-59,47.4-107,105.8-107s105.8,48,105.8,107
 c0,18.4-12.4,51.4-35.9,95.4C295.4,329.3,266.5,373.4,250,397.6z">     
            </path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

which works somewhat but seems inelegant, and perhaps also buggy. What I would like is a better way to center the group 'inside' the circle without using JavaScript

It would be nice if I could get rid of the extra SVG element in the middle with its really big viewBox that I'm using to place the pin. So if you can show me how to do it with just a g and make a scaling function that would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use coordinates that contain percentage values, you need an element that has `x` and `y` attributes. `<use>` is such an element, `<g>` is not.

Your live will be easier if you draw your pin centered on the origin of the coordinate system: `translate(-250 -230)`.

After that, you can easily scale it to the size you need: `scale(0.0025)` (remember: multiple transform commands are processed right-to-left.)

Finally, you use the pin template with the same `x` and `y` coordinates as your circle.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <defs>
    <!--center the pin around the origin and scale it to final size-->
    <g id="pin" transform="scale(0.0025) translate(-250 -230)">
      <path d="M250,124.3c-35,0-63.4,28.8-63.4,64.1c0,35.3,28.5,64,63.4,64s63.4-28.8,63.4-64.1C313.4,153,285,124.3,250,124.3z
M250,222c-18.3,0-33.2-15.1-33.2-33.7s14.9-33.7,33.2-33.7s33.2,15.1,33.2,33.7S268.3,222,250,222z" />
      <path d="M250,50.9c-74.9,0-135.8,61.6-135.8,137.4c0,31.3,22.5,84.4,66.9,157.7c32.9,54.4,66.2,100.3,66.6,100.7l2.4,3.3l2.4-3.3
c0.3-0.5,33.7-46.3,66.6-100.7c44.4-73.3,66.9-126.4,66.9-157.7C385.8,112.5,324.9,50.9,250,50.9z M250,397.6
c-16.5-24.3-45.5-68.4-69.9-114c-23.5-44-35.9-77-35.9-95.4c0-59,47.4-107,105.8-107s105.8,48,105.8,107
c0,18.4-12.4,51.4-35.9,95.4C295.4,329.3,266.5,373.4,250,397.6z" />
    </g>
  </defs>
  <!--use the same coordinates for the center of the circle and the pin-->
  <circle cx="50%" cy="1.5" r="1.5" fill="green" />
  <use xlink:href="#pin" x="50%" y="1.5" fill="white" />
</svg>
```